# IntelliJ Custom Project Dependent Taskbar Icons

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-15

I'm wondering if it's possible to configure IntelliJ to run with a custom taskbar icon that is dependent on the project?

Let's say I have two projects Foo and Bar, in folders F and B, respectively, on my machine. In each project folder I have a batch file that launches a fresh instance of IntelliJ 15.0.6 community edition and loads in the relevant project. I'd like the taskbar icons for Foo and Bar to be different, ideally based on icons that are in the folders F and B. Is this possible?

Comment: Why?  What benefit does this provide?

Comment: @duffymo I can identify which project is which by just looking at the taskbar.

Comment: I can already tell which project I'm in without any special effort.  Sorry, I don't see it.

Comment: If you have firefox open for example, and then you want to return to project Foo, but it's not open, you can click on the taskbar icon that corresponds to Foo. Without the icons, you have to hover over the identical IntelliJ taskbar icons to see which project is which by the hover text.

Comment: Never a problem for me.  Sorry, don't see the need for the extra complexity.

Comment: @ColmBhandal you are not alone, there is already a request for that submitted several years ago: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122393. Feel free to vote.

Comment: Ah, thanks @CrazyCoder! I am feeling a mixture of disappointment and relief that I'm not in a dark corner by myself.

Comment: Exactly what i needed. If you work on 3 projects at the same time, swiching projects is hard and distracting. This kind of a feature would be very beneficial. This also would save me from  clicking file->open and go to the project folder through all the folder structure from C: to Desktop and find the project folder at least every time. This feature would be great.